# Executing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2017 through Python

Tags: python, sql-server, cursor, commit, pyodbc

I'm executing a stored procedure that loops through a table using a cursor, goes through 20,000 scenarios, and then inserts rows based on different join conditions for each scenario.  When I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, it takes approximately 5 hours.

However, when I attempt to run it via a Python script, it takes about 3x longer.  Here is my code in Python:

```
import pyodbc 

#Database connection
server = '<server name>'
db = '<db name>'
process_start = datetime.now()

sql = """exec dbo.sp_loop_cursor_execute_insert"""
conn.execute(sql) 
conn.commit()

#close connection     
conn.close()
```

I suspect it has something to do with how committing works, where it only commits once the entire stored procedure is run.  I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without adding the looping functionality in Python?

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2018. There's a 2017 and a 2019, but there was no release in 2018. Also, in terms of your Stored Procedure, using a `CURSOR` sounds like a major design flaw (though not what you're asking here), as it'll be really slow. Also, it has the `sp_` prefix which is reserved by Microsoft for **S**pecial **P**rocedures, and it's use should be avoided, as it comes with the chance of your Procedure suddenly not working, and it *does* have a performance impact. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: How would you recommend performing 21,000 join permutations if not through dynamic SQL via a cursor?

Comment: *Why* would you need a query with 21,000 joins?! Sounds like you need to review your design here ata very fundamental level.

Comment: We have 2 data sources with name, address, date of birth, and other potential identifiers like social security number. The data quality is poor on both sides so we need to create variations on this data (Such as first and last initial, last 4 of ssn). All of the permutations amount to 21,000 “scenarios”. We’d like to determine situations where the data matches and it looks like the same person - for example the first and last initials AND date of birth match in one bucket vs. just initials. How might you tackle this?